# Crashing application on ios7 with DT set to iOS5 ( UIKeyAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets -is not an integer number)

Tags: ios, ios5, ios7

Had such an issue:

There are 2 storyboards in my project -  for ipad and for iphone. Deployment target is set to iOS 5. When I try to run it on iOS7 using iPad-Simulator app crashes with message -

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeInt32ForKey:]: value for key    
(UIKeyAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets) is not an integer number
```

The strange thing is that iPhone simulator runs well.

Storyboard settings are set to:

1)Opens in XCode5

2)Builds for Project DT

3)Views as iOS 7 and later.

4)XCode 5 dp4.

Comment: because the insets are not integers indeed, the insets are structs. therefore the error message is correct. more info of the insets are here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: yes,I know this. The question is - why these insets are understood as ints by xcode and how to fix it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software that is not finalized yet, meaning any answers would be meaningless once the final product is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your storyboard select your view / navigation controller and for view controller layout make sure `Adjust Scroll View Insets` is checked.